# Changes in a MutableState are reverted after calling popBackStack()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I have two `@Composable` screens which are connected by a `NavHostController`. Let's call them **Screen 1** and **Screen 2**.

They're both sharing a `ViewModel` that is injected by `hiltViewModel()`. This `ViewModel` contains a `state` value (`true` by default) wrapped in a data class `UiState` and exposes method to change that state (to `false`).

```kotlin
data class UiState(
    var state: Boolean
)
```

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class StateViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val uiState: MutableState<UiState> = mutableStateOf(UiState(true))

    fun setStateToFalse() {
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(state = false)
    }
}
```

**Screen 1** is based on the `UiState` and displays data based on it. You can also navigate to the **Screen 2** by clicking the button on the **Screen 1**:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen1(
    navController: NavHostController,
    stateViewModel: StateViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val uiState = remember { stateViewModel.uiState }

    Button(
        onClick = { navController.navigate("Screen2") }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "State value: " + if (uiState.value.state) "true" else "false"
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

After navigating to **Screen 2** we can change the state to `false` and immediately after that call `popBackStack()` to navigate back to the **Screen 1**:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen2(
    navController: NavHostController,
    stateViewModel: StateViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Button(
        onClick = { 
            stateViewModel.setStateToFalse()

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Change state to false")
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, after the calls to `setStateToFalse()` and `popBackStack()` I end up at the **Screen 1** that tells me that the `state` is still `true` while it should be `false`:

[image]

And this is how I expected the **Screen 1** to look like:

[image]

I have debugged the application and the `state` is changed to `false` in the **Screen 2** but later I could see that on the **Screen 1** it remains `true`. I'm still pretty new to Jetpack Compose and Navigation Components so I might be missing something obvious. Even if so, please help me :)

Comment: `hiltViewModel()` (and `viewModel()`) are going to create a ViewModel scoped to that individual destination, which means your Screen 2 has a completely different ViewModel instance than Screen 1. Were you expecting those to be the exact same instance? It sounds like you are almost trying to return a result to the previous screen?

Comment: No, I don't want to pass any results. This is a simplification of a bigger app. But now I see I need a shared view model for those two screens and now I'm wondering if it is possible to do with Dagger Hilt.

Comment: Shared ViewModels using Hilt and Navigation Compose is [specifically covered in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation).